# How to reload AppleFileServer without unloading it?

Tags: linux, mac-osx

I am using this commands to restart my AppleFileServer for sharing.
But how I can reload it, without killing, or unloading it?

```
sudo killall DirectoryService
sudo AppleFileServer
sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.AppleFileServer.plist
sudo launchctl load -F /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.AppleFileServer.plist
```

P.S. The reason I'm asking when I kill it or unload, connection is getting disconnected. I want to reload it without losing connection.

Answer (score 0):

If it's OSX Server, use `sudo serveradmin start/stop afp`.